# SQL Sum Sales for a week based on previous week range

Tags: sql, teradata

Need help with SQL query in resolving the below problem:

Input table has Product ID, Week and sales which is unique, while columns Start and End Week column are the range based on which I want to sum up sales for that particular week.

[image: input table]

From the Input table we want to extract the Product ID along with Week and get the sum of sales based on the week being between start week and end week range.

The Sales value against each Product ID and Week is the sum of sales based on the corresponding start and end week for that product and week combination in the input table.

[image: output table]

I was trying to do a self join on the input table but realized it would not work as I need to join on both Product ID and Week which will nullify the objective.

```
Select a.Product ID, a.Week, Sum(a.Sales) 
from Input as a, Input as b 
  where a.Product ID = b.Product ID 
  and a.Week between b.Start Week and b.End Week 
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Ok, what's the actual question? What issue are you having with your query? What *is* your query?

Comment: I was trying to do a self join on the input table but realized it would not work as I need to join on both Product ID and Week which will nullify the objective. Select a.Product ID, a.Week, Sum(a.Sales) from Input as a, Input as b where a.Product ID = b.Product ID group by 1,2

Answer (score 4):

You just need to switch to an Outer Join:

```
Select a.Product ID, a.Week, Sum(a.Sales)
from Input as a LEFT JOIN Input as b 
  ON a.Product ID = b.Product ID 
 and a.Week between b.Start Week and b.End Week 
group by 1,2
```

This should result in a better plan than Alec's subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not crazy about the sub query, but it should at least get you started:

```
SELECT
  a.ProductID,
  a.Week,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(b.Sales)
    FROM
      Table b
    WHERE
      b.ProductID = a.ProductID AND
      b.Week BETWEEN a.StartWeek AND a.EndWeek
  ) as CumulativeSales
FROM
  Table a
```

Comment: thanks Alec, but is there a way to do it without using sub query?